# DateTime Column not Displaying time correctly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with a DateTime column. I update it using a stored procedure like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (DateTimeColumn) VALUES (GETDATE())
```

I have tried using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but still the column displays the time as 00:00:00

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedure]
    @foo(50) = null,
    @foo(50) = null,
    @foo= null,
    @foo(200)= null,
    @InsertTS datetime =null,
    @foo(50)  = null
AS
    SET @InsertTS = ISNULL(@InsertTS, GETDATE())
    SET @foo = ISNULL(@foo, user)

    INSERT INTO table (foo, foo, foo, foo, InsertTS, foo)
    VALUES (@foo, @foo, @foo, @foo, @InsertTS, @foo)
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have a trigger defined on this table?

Comment: Are you sure the datatype for the column is `datetime` and not just `date`?

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` work well, can you post the Stored procedure

Comment: @peterm, I actually didn't create this table. I'm just looking at its design through SSMS's Describe feature.

Comment: @Raj, yes, I am sure. I'm looking at its design using Describe.

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec9fb/1

Comment: Please post your table definition here.

Comment: check the parameter value for @InsertTS which is passed to SP.

Comment: @Naveen it is DateTime

Comment: I meant if the value passed to this parameter has only date it will insert 0 for time stamp by default. Are you sure you are passing date along with time to SP?

Comment: @Naveen Isn't that what ISNULL(@InsertTS, GETDATE()); is for?

Comment: Check my answer. I have given explanation properly there.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Look closer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did a workaround to prevent the issue from happening by:

1. Removing `SET @InsertTS = ISNULL(@InsertTS, GETDATE())`
2. Explicitly placing `GETDATE()` in the `INSERT` statement:

   INSERT INTO Table (InsertTS) VALUES (GETDATE())

Somehow the `ISNULL()` function is only getting the date out of the `GETDATE()` function.

Thank you for all the replies.

Comment: If you found the comment is rude, I am really sorry. But the answer which you mentioned above raises this question.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't believe it deserves a -1. LOL

Comment: Sorry mate, that is not me. I din't gave it -1.

Comment: I edited the answer from suggesting it's a "fix" to a "workaround".

Answer (score 0):

Your SP looks good and it will insert proper date-time value. Make sure you are passing proper date-time value to `@InsertTS datetime` parameter. If it is null then only it will consider `GETDATE()` value which will have proper value. As you mentioned it has `00:00:00` for timestamp, I believe you are passing only Date value without time to the SP which is assigning  `00:00:00` to time-stamp by default since its `DATETIME` datatype..

For example if you pass **2014-01-15** to `@InsertTS` it will insert **2014-01-15 00:00:00.000**. If you pass null value it will insert `GETDATE()` value i.e example : **2014-01-15 14:48:24.757**

Run the below SQL and you will understand better i guess.

```
declare @d datetime = '2014-01-15'
declare @s datetime = null
select ISNULL(@d,GETDATE())
select ISNULL(@s,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Again, isn't that what SET @InsertTS = ISNULL(@InsertTS, GETDATE()) is for?

Comment: Try to understand what is ISNULL. I think you are confused.

Comment: Maybe I am, but if you look at the start of the SP, the parameter is set to null, then it is set to GETDATE() using the ISNULL(@InsertTS, GETDATE()) expression. Doesn't that assign GETDATE to the paramter if it is null which it is?

Comment: The null is assigned to "@InsertTS" datetime =null, only if you don't pass any parameter to SP. That is why i am asking you to check, what value you are passing to "@InsertTS".

Comment: Are you sure "@InsertTS" is null and GETDATE() is assigned to it?

Comment: The code doesn't pass anything to that paramater because it gets its value within the SP using SET @InsertTS = ISNULL(@InsertTS, GETDATE()).

Comment: OK. But there is no problem in SP. It will insert timestamp if the column type is datetime. You can see comment from @Jamiec above.

Comment: BTW, if it doesn't pass anything why you have it in parameter list?

Comment: I know that. I've already checked the column type as I've mentioned in the commments above.

Comment: @Nath: As Naveen said, GETDATE() will invariably produce a datetime value, with TIME. So the only way you can end up with 0 as time is either because a DATE (not datetime) is passed to the procedure, the column type in the insert table is DATE type, or there's for example a trigger there changing the result.

Comment: The column is datetime, no value for the InsertTS is passed to the procedure because its value is set within the procedure using GETDATE(), and lastly, I just checked and, no, there are no triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Please Cast it to `Datetime` after `ISNULL()` Function.

E.g:

```
declare @d datetime = '2014-01-15'
declare @s datetime = Null
select Cast(ISNULL(@d,GETDATE()) AS Datetime)
select Cast(ISNULL(@s,GETDATE()) AS Datetime)
```